# Does Class.getDeclaredConstructor return only public constructors?

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

Going over the documentation for this method here: [getDeclaredConstructor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29)

I could not see any reference of it returning only public constructors.

My problem is that I have the following piece of code:

```
protected BaseClass internalCreate(String className) throws Exception {

    Class<? extends BaseClass> classObj = Class.forName(className)
                    .asSubclass(BaseClass.class);

    Constructor<?> ctor = classObj.getDeclaredConstructor((Class[]) null);
    ctor.setAccessible(true);

    return (BaseClass) ctor.newInstance();
}
```

When running this method for a class that has a default constructor visibility (package private), i am getting a MissingMethod exception. Changing the constructor to public fixes the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method returns the constructor declared in the class, public or not. But it does not mean that you can instatiate an instance with the returned constructor, this is why you're getting the error. If access is not allowed you call to call setAccessible(true) on such Constructor. This is the same as with getDeclaredMethod and getDeclaredFields.